# Restfb confusing exception message

Tags: facebook, restfb

I am trying to post to facebook group using `RestFB` library but I get:

```
com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient makeRequestAndProcessResponse:
```

`Facebook responded with HTTP status code 403 and response body: {"error":{"message":"(#200)` `Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include a target_id","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}`

Even thought my acess token is an application access token.

```
 {
         "name": "LottoShop",
         "access_token": "ACCESS_TOKEN_CODE",
         "category": "Application",
         "id": "xxxx"
      },
```

I get the above access token when I invoke

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=MY_OWN_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

In my personal opinion, this Facebook Graph API is convoluted!

Comment: Related to currently open bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/380937985301371

Comment: thanks Igy, but the exception code I get is different from the one you mentioned. Are they related?

Comment: I thought so, as that bug report is related to users acting as pages not working correctly at a low-ish level, this would also explain the error you're seeing assuming you're trying to update a page's feed

Comment: Yes I am trying to update a page's feed, the error is sporadic though.